# Numpy list of arrays to concatenated ordered matrix of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays, where each array is of the same rank, for example each array has the same shape of `(H, W, C)`.

Assume the list I have has 12 such arrays, e.g.

```py
my_list = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L]
```

What I want is given a grid size (in the sample below the grid is 3x4), create a single matrix **with the same rank of each array** that places the first array in the top left and the last array in the bottom right in an ordered manner, e.g.

```
[A, B, C, D, 
 E, F, G, H, 
 I, J, K, L]
```

This is only a pseudo result, as the result should be in this case a matrix with the shape of `(H*3, W*4, C)`. The example above is only for placement clarification.

How can I achieve that using numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
h = 7
w = 5
c = 10
grid = 3*4
##Creating sample data for list
a = np.random.rand(grid,h,w,c)
my_list = list(a)
#### 
my_array = np.array(my_list) ## shape (grid,h,w,c)
my_array = my_array.reshape(3,4,h,w,c)
my_array = my_array.transpose(0,2,1,3,4)

your_req_array = my_array.reshape(3*h,4*w,c)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please elaborate on the solution? The reshape 5 dimension part and the transpose please

Comment: @bluesummers my_list has 12 elements. With my_array.reshape(3,4,h,w,c), I am creating a 3x4 matrix grid from elements of my_list.

 my_array.transpose(0,2,1,3,4) is swapping the dimensions of h to 2nd place and 4 to 3rd place, so that I can reshape to (3*h,4*w,c)